# How to use different values on two Dynamically generated Comboboxes

Tags: c#, c++, .net, wpf, binding

I am a C++ developer and recently started working on WPF. I am sorry for the weird title since I wasnt sure what to put. In my app, I need to dynamically generate 2 groupboxes which contain buttons, labels, textbox, combobox's and so on. And once its done, I need to perform some operation on these controls.

I have 2 xaml files `PCMGenView.xaml` and `PCMGenWidgetView.xaml` where `PCMGenWidgetView.xaml` file has the groupbox and is added to the `PCMGenView.xaml` file. I also have 2 viewmodel classes and a model class. Well let me show you how I have done it:

**PCMGenView.xaml**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PGenDataTemplate">
        <WrapPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Margin="5,5,0,0"/>
            <local:PCMGenWidgetView Margin="5,10,5,5"/>
        </WrapPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PGenDataTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding PGenWidgets}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

**PCMGenWidgetView.xaml:**

```
<Grid>
    <GroupBox Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" Name="groupBox1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto">
        <Grid >
              <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding PreScalarList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPreScalarList, Mode=OneWayToSource}" SelectedIndex="0" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="PCMGenControlCombo" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="110" /> 
              // Radio Button, Buttons etc are present too                          
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

**PCMGenWidgetView.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class PCMGenWidgetView : UserControl
{
    PCMGenWidgetViewModel mPCMGenWidgetViewModel = new PCMGenWidgetViewModel();

    public PCMGenWidgetView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = mPCMGenWidgetViewModel;            
    }
}
```

**PCMGenViewModel:**

```
public ObservableCollection<PCMGenWidgetViewModel> PGenWidgets { get; set; }

    public PCMGenViewModel()
    {
        PGenWidgets = new ObservableCollection<PCMGenWidgetViewModel>();
        PGenWidgets.Add(new PCMGenWidgetViewModel { Description = "PCM Generator 1", ID = 0 });
        PGenWidgets.Add(new PCMGenWidgetViewModel { Description = "PCM Generator 2", ID = 1 });            
    }
```

**PCMGenWidgetViewModel:**

```
private string _description;
    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return _description;
        }

        set
        {
            _description = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Description");
        }
    }

public ObservableCollection<string> PreScalarList
    {
        get { return _PreScalarList; }
        set
        {
            _PreScalarList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PreScalarList");
        }
    }

    private string _selectedPreScalarList;
    public string SelectedPreScalarList
    {
        get { return _selectedPreScalarList; }
        set
        {
            _selectedPreScalarList = value;
            int Listvalue = PreScalarList.IndexOf(_selectedPreScalarList);
            int ListFinalVal = Listvalue + 1;
            SelectedPreScalar(ListFinalVal);
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedPreScalarList");
        }
    }

    private int _ID;
    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return _ID;
        }

        set
        {
            _ID = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ID");
        }
    }

    public void SelectedPreScalar(int Select)
    {
        int bitMask;
        bitMask = (0 == ID) ? 0xCF : 0x3F;  // ID always shows 0
        m_controlRegs[0] &= Convert.ToByte(bitMask);
        //m_refClock[0] = Convert.ToByte(18432000 * 2);                                             
    }
```

Now this gives me 2 groupboxes on startup :) In my combobox I have `A,B,C,D` as items. Have a look at the combobox binding at how I am able to retrieve the selected value from the combobox. Here I wanna perform the same operation on all these controls but if different values. Well I mean to say something like this which I did in my C++ app:

```
for( i = 0;  i < 2; i++) //Constructor: Here 2 is used because we have 2 groupboxes
{
    m_pcmGenPrescalar[i] = new ComboBox(String::empty);
    m_pcmGenPrescalar[i]->addItem(String(T("div 1")), 1);
    m_pcmGenPrescalar[i]->addItem(String(T("div 15")), 2);
    m_pcmGenPrescalar[i]->addItem(String(T("div 255")), 3);
    m_pcmGenPrescalar[i]->addItem(String(T("div 65535")), 4);
    m_pcmGenPrescalar[i]->setEditableText(false);
    m_pcmGenPrescalar[i]->setSelectedId(1, true);
    m_pcmGenPrescalar[i]->addListener(this);
    addAndMakeVisible(m_pcmGenPrescalar[i]);
}

for( i = 0;  i < 2; i++) //Here 2 is used because we have 2 groupboxes
{       
    if(m_pcmGenPrescalar[i] == comboBox) //PreScalar Combobox
    {
        unsigned char bitMask = (0 == i) ? 0xCF : 0x3F; Takes the value of i
        m_controlRegs[0] &= bitMask;
        m_refClock[i] = 18432000 * 2;
    }
```

If you notice above code, you will find the `for loop` creating the combobox two times and based on which ever combobox is selected value is taken in `i`. I.e. if first combobox selection is changed then `unsigned char bitMask = (0 == i) ? 0xCF : 0x3F;` becomes `unsigned char bitMask = (0 == 0) ? 0xCF : 0x3F;` if second then, `unsigned char bitMask = (0 == 1) ? 0xCF : 0x3F;`

This is my query. How can I get to know which combobox I have used. Whether I have used PCM Gen 1 combo or PCM Gen 2 combo? This is a tricky situation for me. please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an ID-property:

```
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public void SelectedPreScalar(int Select)
    {
        int bitMask;
        bitMask = (0 == ID) ? 0xCF : 0x3F; 
        m_controlRegs[0] &= Convert.ToByte(bitMask);
        m_refClock[0] = Convert.ToByte(18432000 * 2); 
    }
```

But you also can use a BitMask-Property, which you set at the instanciation:

```
    public string BitMask {get;set;}
    public void SelectedPreScalar(int Select)
    {
        m_controlRegs[0] &= Convert.ToByte(BitMask);
        m_refClock[0] = Convert.ToByte(18432000 * 2); 
    }
```

Depending on how you decided, your PCGenViewModel-constructor could look like:

```
    public PCMGenViewModel()
    {
        PGenWidgets = new ObservableCollection<PCMGenWidgetViewModel>();
        PGenWidgets.Add(new PCMGenWidgetViewModel { Description = "PCM Generator 1", BitMask="0xCF" });
        PGenWidgets.Add(new PCMGenWidgetViewModel { Description = "PCM Generator 2", BitMask="0x3F" });            
    }
```

or

```
    public PCMGenViewModel()
    {
        PGenWidgets = new ObservableCollection<PCMGenWidgetViewModel>();
        PGenWidgets.Add(new PCMGenWidgetViewModel { Description = "PCM Generator 1", ID=0 });
        PGenWidgets.Add(new PCMGenWidgetViewModel { Description = "PCM Generator 2", ID=1 });            
    }
```

I would recommend using the second suggestion, because if you add a third groupbox, you dont have to change your SelectedPreScalar-method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But did you understand what I was trying to explain??? I have generated 2 groupboxes which has combobox. I just want to know which combobox I have used. PCm Gen 1 or PCM Gen 2. Both of them will have different values in `bitMask`, `controlRegs` etc. My query is simple. How will I make sure my dynamically generated combobox behaves independent of each other? Can we use a ID which returns me which PCM Gen I have used?

Comment: Where do you want to know which ComboBox you used? In the `SelectedPreScalar`-method of your PCMGenWidgetViewModel? Yes, then you can easily use an ID-property.

Comment: Yes. `SelectedPreScalar` is part of my PCMGenWidgetViewModel class. Since it holds the control when combobox is changed, I need to know how can I achieve it using ID? When I say ID, I mean put ID = 0 for PCMGen 1 and ID = 1 for PCMGen2 and whenever I chnage combobox item in any of the PCMGen's I get to know which one have i selected. Can you help me achieve this? :)

Comment: Well tried the ID method and whenever I select any combobox, ID value is always 0.

Comment: You have to set the ID when you create an instance of your PCMGenWidgetViewModel (last code-block in my answer), otherwise its always 0 (default value of an int-variable).

Comment: Yes I did that. I have set ID = 0 and ID = 1 in my constructor along with description. But still its showing 0.

Comment: Could you update your code in your question (PCGenWidgetViewModel an PCGenViewModel-Contructor)?

Comment: So even if you select an item from the second GroupBox' ComboBox, the ID is 0?

Comment: Yes ID is still 0. I think something is wrong with ID. May be its not getting Notified when changed.

Comment: No, thats not the problem, you dont even need the propertyChanged-method in the setter, because your not binding anything to it. Please make a breakpoint in the SelectedPreScalar-method and look what the Description-properties value is.

Comment: Does the textbox above your PCGenWidgetView show the right description-text?

Comment: yes it shows correct text. PCM generator 1, PCM generator 2. Can you send move to chat command from your side??? Its throwing error here

Comment: No I cant move to chat, I get an error everytime. Could you add the code-behind of you PCMGenWidgetView?

Comment: HA! I knew it! Remove this.DataContext=mPCMGenWidgetViewModel; With this part youre overriding the DatContext which it gets throught the ItemsSource-Property of the ItemsControl. Now it should work.